# jQuery fadeIn/fadeOut in an Unordered List

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to use jQuery's fadeIn/fadeOut effects on images that are being used as buttons in an unordered list.  I want to be able to have the hovered image fade in quickly and out slowly on mouseout.  The problem I am having is that I am trying to do this as horizontal menu with floated `<li>` tags.  I created a jsfiddle with as simple of an example as I could.  The list in the example contains only 1 list item, but it will actually have 4 or 5.

In order to position the hover images I have created a second `<ul>` so that it is positioned on top of the other list.  What is happening now is that when hovered it does the fadeIn fadeOut twice.  I assume that this is happening once for each of the `<ul>`.

Is there something I can do to position two images on top of each other, within the same `<li>`?  Or another(better) way altogether to accomplish this?  Any help is appreciated.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Qb97f/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get rid of the second `<ul>` by putting the two images within your `#menu1`, and then adding this few properties to your CSS:

```css
#menu1 {
    position: relative;
}

#hovbutton1 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}
```

That way you're positioning your hover image in an absolute position relative to its parent,  so when shown, it will appear on top of the other one.

Here's the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/seiseises/Qb97f/1/), hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks! All I needed to do, and so simple.

Comment: You're welcome! And by the way, in case you didn't know, if you just want to create text effects on hover (glow, color change, etc.) you can do it with just CSS properties like `text-shadow` and `transition`. No need of images or jQuery, and that means faster code :)